# WP_Query multiple values with Meta key?

Tags: wordpress

I am really facing so much problem in fetching result of multiple values and single meta key. 
Example:
I have 10 Post of 'EGG' word.
I have 5 Post of 'Butter' word.

Now i am using below query to fetch result. It suppose to show 15 post in result but its not showing total result.

```
$args = array(
'numberposts'   => -1,
'post_type'     => 'recipes',
'meta_query'    => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'key'       => 'ingredients_repeat_%_name',
        'compare'   => 'LIKE',
        'value'     => 'Butter',
    ),
    array(
        'key'       => 'ingredients_repeat_%_name',
        'compare'   => 'LIKE',
        'value'     => 'Egg',
    ),
)
```

);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the `numberposts` try `posts_per_page` instead. You can learn more about [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters)

Comment: I don't know how i can be so stupid. Result was fine. Only post_per_page was not showing full result. Thanks